# Proper approach on async/await method including Lambda

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

I would like to show two paradigms about async programming and listen to your comments.

**A.**

Let's say you have created a method like the following in a library to use it from your GUI clients.

```
public async Task<TestObject> DoSomeWork(string aParam1, object aParam2)
{
   TestObject testObj = new TestObject();
   ...fill in params to testObj...
   await MethodCallAsync(testObj);
   ....do other work synchronous.....
   ....continue fill testObj properties...
   await Task.Delay(1000) // just a delay for no reason
   ...continue synchronous work.....
   return testObj;
}
```

Ok, but this will chop my GUI context into small calling pieces, right? or I don't know if from the moment you declare a method async it will create a Task for all the operations inside?

If yes then great, no problem we can just declare it async and move on with our lives.

Lets say no and I would like to take the following approach so I won't disturb the GUI at all until my whole method call finishes and take the result so do something in my calling method.

**B.**

Another approach would be.

```
public async Task<TestObject> DoSomeWork(string aParam1, object aParam2)
{
   TestObject testObj = new TestObject()
   ..fill state params....
   return await Task.Factory.StartNew((state) =>
   {
      //But now I need to do async/await in here
      // is it a good practice to async await lambdas?
      // async/await practices say it's ok as long sas it is not becoming async void
      // which in our case is not.
      await MethodCallAsync(testObj);
       ....do other work synchronous.....
       ....continue fill state properties...
       await Task.Delay(1000) // just a delay for no reason
       ...continue synchronous work.....
       return state; // Our state and TestObject to examine after completion

   }, testObj);
}
```

Our problem now it's not only if we should asyncify the lambda, say you do it, it the will return a `Task<Task<TestObject>>` and definitely we don't want that.

You should call this up in the pipeline, most probably your GUI class.

```
private async void SomethingClickedOrTouched(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   await RunThisAsyncToDoYourJob();
}

private async Task RunThisAsyncToDoYourJob()
{
   TestObject testObj = await myObject.DoSomeWork("param1", anotherObject);
}
```

It just bugs me a little and I really want into detail with async programming.

So, is A paradigm the correct approach anyway, and use the B paradigm only when the Task lambda inside code is completely synchronous?
Thank you in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proper way to write an `async` method is to use `ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false)` whenever you *don't* need to resume on the captured context. This is normally done for all "library" code.

> this will chop my GUI context into small calling pieces, right?

Yes (since you're not using `ConfigureAwait`).

> or I don't know if from the moment you declare a method async it will create a Task for all the operations inside?

Yes, `async` will create a `Task` that represents the `async` method. However, the fact that there is a `Task` does not mean that its code is running on a background thread.

> it the will return a `Task<Task<TestObject>>` and definitely we don't want that.

I'd like to know where everyone is getting the idea of using `Task.Factory.StartNew` for asynchronous tasks. [`Task.Run` is superior if you want to run code on a background thread](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx).

---

I have an [`async` intro on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) that you may find helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will definitely read the blog post. I have put my hands on async and want to go further. I use ConfigureAwait to some methods, I read your MSDN article, really helpful. I don't in my current situation to resume on the captured context, no GUI controls or anything, but what happens with the return value to the client, any impact? Yes, I understand the Task creation but no background thread, so the solution is Task.Run to make my work on a background thread and return my value.

Comment: You don't need to use `Task.Run` unless you have long-running CPU-bound work you need to do. Whether you use `ConfigureAwait` or not, it doesn't affect how the returned `Task` is handled (not quite true but close enough).

Comment: Bottom line, I should use Task.Run only when I have synchronous code and want make it awaitable to the client.

Comment: Yes, and I would actually go a step further: if you have synchronous code, let the client decide whether *they* want to call it synchronously or asynchronously. So I don't recommend `Task.Run` in any of your "library" code; the client can just use `Task.Run` when they *call* it.

Comment: Nice, never choose to asyncify your synchronous code and even if you need to use it on your code run Task.Run. Makes sense. Thank you Stephen.